# Display today events in SharePoint 2010 Calendar

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-calendar

I want to display today events from the SharePoint 2010 calendar list on the home page. I have issues with displaying events that are spanning for more than 1 day. Ex:- if the event is from Aug 21 to Aug 25 9am to 10 am, and if today is aug 22, need help with filter condition to display the event.

Comment: Since I'm not sure where you are writing the filter, I will just answer with the logic and not the syntax:

IF DATEDIF([Start Date], [End Date], "d") >= 1, THEN IF TODAY() <= [End Date] SHOW EVENT.

I believe that logic should get you the results you want, but please let me know if I've missed the mark on this one.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a new view and set filters like below. And then add list view web part in the home page and select view to the new view.

**Start Time** is less than or equal to **[Today]**

And

**End Time** is greater than or equal to **[Today]**

[image]